# Running ageadjust.indirect for each row in R

Tags: r

I'm using ageadjust.indirect on census tract-like geographical areas.
I have two data frames for the geographical data; `cases` and `pop`.
I also have two vectors for standard population and standard case count; `standardpop` and `standardcnt` respectively. They have a length of 5 for 5 age groups.

The data frames containing the area data (`cases` and `pop`) are both 671 rows each and have 5 columns (for the 5 age groups.)

I would like to run `ageadjust.indirect()` to get an age adjusted rate for each area and I use this code to try and accomplish that:

```
ageadjust.indirect(cases, pop, stdcount = standardcnt, stdpop = standardpop)
```

However, this just returns a single adjusted rate with all the observed cases at once.

How can I run ageadjust.indirect() for each row of `cases` and `pop` to get an adjusted rate per geographical unit?

Comment: @akrun Yes, I use the total age distribution as standardpop and total case distribution as standardcnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option may be to loop over the sequence of rows of one of the data (as both have the same dimensions) and apply the function on the subset of datasets

```
out <-  lapply(seq_len(nrow(cases)), function(i)
     ageadjust.indirect(cases[i,], pop[i,],
           stdcount = standardcnt, stdpop = standardpop))
```

---

Or use `pmap` with elements in a `list`

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
list(cases, pop) %>%
           pmap(~ ageadjust.indirect(count = ..1, 
                       pop = ..2,
                       stdcount = standardcnt,
                       stdpop = standardpop))
```

Comment: The first suggestion did what I wanted! I just need some post processing because the ageadjust function outputs a list of two dataframes.